# Make every item of a string an array with semicolumn

Tags: javascript

I have a sting like this:

```
"a;b;x"
```

and I want to convert it to

```
"a"; "b"; "x"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to to return an array that you join at the end of the operation.

The map operation merely checks to see if the current element is the last in the array. If it is, don't append a semi-colon, then return the transformed element.

```
var output = str.split(';').map(function (el, i, arr) {
    return i === (arr.length - 1) ? '"' + el + '"' : '"' + el + '";'
}).join(' ');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9dL73e1f/)

Or perhaps the slightly easier to understand:

```
var output = str.split(';').map(function (el, i, arr) {
    var end = i === (arr.length - 1) ? '' : ';';
    return '"' + el + '"' + end;
}).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

you are searching for `split()` method

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var str = "a;b;x";
var str_split = str.split(";");
var result = '"';

for (var i = 0; i < str_split.length; i++) {
  result += str_split[i] + '"; "' }

result = result.substring(0, result.length - 3);
```

have a nice day ;)

Comment: yea bro, but the step to your result is not that far :D wait, i update my answer

Answer (score 1):

This regexp wraps each letter by quote symbol and adding space symbol with new ";".And removes from end last "; "

```
 var result = "a;b;x".replace(/(\w)(;)*/g,'"$1"; ').replace(/;\s+$/g,"");
 console.log(result) // '"a"; "b"; "x"'
```

- $1 - is letter

Comment: You need some spaces between the letters.

Comment: I am added a space symbol.